# How can I validate a URL before the request gets to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Our service uses ASP.NET Core and in the application pipeline, we have several middlewares which are configured in StartUp.cs `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method.

The middlewares are added by this method:
`app.UseMiddleware<Type>();`

I would like to validate the `HttpContext.Request.Path` and make sure it can hit one of the controllers. How can I get the list of available routes (controller path) in the middleware code or is there even a simpler way to see if this certain request path will hit one of the registered controller? We used `xxxxcontroller : ControllerBase` and a `[Route("controller/{version}/{id}]` attribute to register the controller.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you'll need a module-equivalent in `middleware` stuff, like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at Asp.net core identity, If I understood what you`re looking for, you need to use roles to guarantee access to certain routes.

Comment: I know a bit about the identity, user claim stuff, i dont actually think that it is about the identity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get a list of all routes and check that the path is for a valid route but you can use middleware to check the response status code after MVC runs and if the status code is a 404 then you know it wasn't a valid route and you can handle it accordingly.

The `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` extension method basically uses this approach to handle not only 404 errors but all error status codes.